# How to add counters to User-Defined Functions in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
>>> Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maximillian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python-koding\steinsakspapir.py", line 64, in scissors
    botwin += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'botwin' referenced before assignment
```

-Tried to remove botwin and youwin from rest of the code
-Tried to use youwin = youwin + 1

```
    def scissors():
        bot = random.randint(1,3)
       user = 3
       if user == bot:
            printfuver = ("Stalemate, booth players choose scissors")
           printfu = Label(lowerframe, text=printfuver, fg="blue")
            printfu.pack()
        if user == 3 and bot == 1:
            printfuver = ("Rock crushes scissors, bot win! ")
            printfu = Label(lowerframe, text=printfuver, fg="red")
            printfu.pack()
            botwin += 1
        if user == 3 and bot == 2:
            printfuver = ("Scissors cut paper, you win! ")
            printfu = Label(lowerframe, text=printfuver, fg="green")
            printfu.pack()
            youwin += 1
```

Simply want botwin to increase with a value of 1 after each time the fuction is ran.

thanks in advance

Comment: if you want to increase the value by 1, you need to ensure the value exists beforehand. does `botwin` exist? does `youwin` exist? you can use them as global variables and increment outside.

Comment: This may or may not be the issue, but it looks like you have an indentation issue in the `if user == bot:` block. `printfu = Lable(lowerframe, text=printfuver, fg="blue")` is one space back. Correct that and see if your code works.

Comment: thanks you, it worked. had to make it global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the indentation error in your code, this is probably a scope issue. Check to make sure you have `botwin = 0` or something like it somewhere in your code. If that code is in a function or otherwise out of global scope, put it at the top of your code. Then, in all functions that reference it, put `global botwin` at the beginning of your function as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function).

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks. Had botwin = 0 at the top but had to type global botwin before it as you said